# 'SQLite' Database is Locked Error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Whilst creating an 'INSERT', I have included the "try and except" approach to alert the user to when a duplicate primary key is entered, using a message box. Nevertheless, when a duplicate key is entered, the next time the 'INSERT' is ran, it gives the following error:

> "sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked"

Is there is another approach to solving this issue at all?

I've added the 'INSERT' below to the post with the relevant table creation.

**Insert Function**

```
    try:
        conn=sqlite3.connect("Homework_Planner.db")
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Email, Password) \
                                                   VALUES  (?,?,?);",(student_ID, student_Email, hashedPassword,))
        conn.commit()
        #Commits changes made to the database.
        conn.close()
        #Closes the database..


    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        messagebox.showinfo('Setup Error!', 'Student ID already exists.')

        x=windows() 
        x.student_Setup()
```

**Table Creation**

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("Homework_Planner.db")
conn.execute (''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student  (
 StudentID             TEXT       PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL,
 Email                 TEXT       NOT NULL,
 Password              TEXT       NOT NULL );''')
```

Comment: Did you try closing the connection after the except block?
conn.close()

Comment: I think that was the primary issue in question @EytanAvisror, after using 'try-with' I removed the .close() function call, but looking back it does look like a logic error on my part as it was closing the db before it made it to "except".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `sqlite3.IntegrityError` is thrown before the connection is closed, this causes your database to lock since it believes that it is still in connection with the application. To prevent this I suggest closing the connection in the `catch` block too to make sure it also gets closed when the error is thrown. Alternatively, you can use a `finally` block to close the connection but just as the previous method, this is prone to errors.

The new and improved way of handling all this is by using a `try-with` block (also known as a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/)). By doing this you open the resource inside the `try` block and it will automatically be closed at the end of it. In your case this could look as follows:

```
try:
    with sqlite3.connect("Homework_Planner.db") as conn:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Email, Password) \ VALUES (?,?,?);",(student_ID, student_Email, hashedPassword,))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    messagebox.showinfo('Setup Error!', 'Student ID already exists.')
    x=windows()
    x.student_Setup()
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken what you explained 'try-with' is the way to go! it handles the query just like 'with-open' -file to close when done...

Comment: Yeah I think a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) is a very elegant construct for purposes like these.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Great little work around that worked, I think the issue was in fact that the 'close' function was being called within "try" and when an incorrect input was given, meaning it would move to the "except" the db was already closed, throwing the error out, again many thanks! :)

Comment: @iamsnaks you are very welcome, I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to accept (and upvote) the answer that solved your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately my upvote's aren't able to be viewed globally, but accepted the answer! @yarwest

Comment: upvoted! just a curious question though, if you have a contextmanager, may I know why you are still calling commit? Also is there a way to specify a callback that gets triggered when the database is not locked anymore

Comment: @PirateApp as it turns out you don't explicitly have to call commit, my bad :) The database is unlocked whenever the transaction is committed, so after the ```try``` block.